# is there a way to get all chars equivalent to given char in a locale

Tags: java, regex, unicode, locale, icu

I am looking into the icu package for java.  What I am looking for as a way of passing a given locale and a given codepoint and getting a list of characters that are "equivalent".

I looking at the POSIX charclass for [=e=] in French, what are all the characters equivalent in French to 'e'?  e, é, è and ê

I looked at the icu package which everyone seems to be using, and didn't find a way to do this.

NOTE: this seems to be the reverse of another question.

Andy

Comment: java.text.Normalizer can decompose code points into several, like `e'`, possibly (not sure) `oe`. Is that meant with "equivalent"?

Comment: equivalent in French to 'e' would be all forms of e characters in French.

Comment: Interesting question- what are you planning to do with the results? Also just looking for all possible chars will not work, because for example "Å" = "AA" in some collators.

Comment: I am writing a regex engine for java that offers the main feature of insinuation of instructions in the regex (ala Perl).  However, this is a fine point of offering a charclass that matches (such as [=ea=]) for all equivalent variations of 'e' and 'a' in a locale.

Comment: see my other comment about http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CanonicalIterator.html

Comment: Lets say that I make my "canonicaliterator" string for the icu for just one character of interest.  Would you say this is a more reliable way to infer the list of character equivalents than parsing and using the JDK Collator rules?  I don't mind bundling icu with my engine.  E.g. you said that a single char would become 2 chars in some JDK collators.  What would happen in this case with icu CanonicalIterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by equivalent, but you can use a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) to see which characters would be sorted together. You can get the default collator from the `Locale`:

```
Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
```

Casting this to a [`RuleBasedCollator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) allows you to do:

```
((RuleBasedCollator)Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE)).getRules();
```

Which will show you the equivalence table.

Comment: I think this answer is the best choice for Java 6 and Java 7.  I will see if there is something similar for icu.

Comment: ICU has the same interface available. http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedCollator.html#getRules()

Answer (score 1):

This may be actually what you want: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CanonicalIterator.html

Comment: Interesting class, but the OP is looking for a something which says that `é` is equivalent to `e`. This class would be if you wanted to see that `e` + `´` is equivalent to `é`

Comment: True. looks like this class is not locale sensitive.